# Unpermitted parameter when trying to allow only one option with a collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got my event categories to work without an unpermitted parameter error if I use the following setup:

```
class Event
     has_many :event_category_joins
     has_many :event_categories, through: :event_category_joins
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_categories

class EventCategoryJoin
     belongs_to :event
     belongs_to :event_category

class EventCategory
     has_many :event_category_joins
     has_many :events, through: event_category_joins

class EventsController
     private

     def event_params
          params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start, :end, :description, :cover_img, :cover_img_alt, event_category_ids: [])
     end

in the view:

= f.collection_select(:event_category_ids, EventCategory.all, :id, :category, {}, {class: "form-select border border-dark", multiple: true})
```

Now, the above works.  But if I don't define multiple: true, it returns a unpermitted parameter: event_category_ids.

If I use multiple: false, it returns unpermitted.

Right now, I only want the user to be able to select ONE category from a dropdown collection of categories that I define with the categories controller.

Is there a way I can get this drop down to work properly?  I have other fields that need to do the same.  Yet at the same time I want the code set up so I can offer multiple selections later if needed.

The other problem I'm having is in the edit view with the multiple: true, it doesn't even show which ones are currently saved in the database.  I can see the array when I go to Rails Console, but it doesn't show it on the edit view.

UPDATE:

Based on the comments given below, I was able to remove the array and now it works as I want it to for a single selection for now.

```
def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :cover_img, :cover_img_alt, :start, :end, :description, :registration_required, :event_category_ids)
  end
```

Comment: Not a ton of context here to work with, but it makes sense that you would need an HTML multiple select option given that your specified parameter is an array (collection). The nature of your question makes me wonder if your models aren't set up to do what you want. You can do a hacky post-submission workaround in the controller but I wouldn't recommend it. Why do your Event records need to be restricted to having one EventCategory _only_ in the form?

Comment: if I remove the array from the permitted list and simply say :event_category_ids and use that param in the form, I get unpermitted.  if I change it to event_category_id then Rails complains of undefined method.  I want a drop down select box that lets the user select only ONE category from a list of categories defined in the EventCategory model and controller.

Comment: @Allison no, he definitely did the model as he wants. `Yet at the same time I want the code set up so I can offer multiple selections later if needed.`

the only problem is `event_category_ids: []` should be `:event_category_ids`

Comment: You both seem to have not read the part where I ended my comment with "WHY do your Event records need to be restricted to having _one_ EventCategory only in the form?"; for the models he's laid out (both in concept and in code), needing to set a _single_ EventCategory instead of doing a multiselect so badly that he goes to SO is counterintuitive + hacking a many-to-many model relationship into 1-1 in the form is asking for bugs. *Great job mansplaining and then writing an answer that repeats the root cause of his issue that I already explained in the first sentence of my comment* @blackbiron

Comment: If you think you need a many-to-many relationship (which conceptually it seems like you should), it's best to implement your form that way or you will need a lot of brittle, hacky code. If it's super important to you to have a form where every one Event has one Category, then implement your models as 1 Category to many Events; then if you ever decide to switch to letting Events have many Categories, write a migration to implement the join table and update your form accordingly. Implementing 3 tables for a use case you can accomplish with 2 is ill-advised.

Comment: @Allison sorry if you feel that way, didn't mean it. and yes, your advise to use 2 tables instead of 3 would be better. but i don't see the possibility of bugs will occur caused by the OP's current scheme. CMIIW

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your log and you should see the difference between `multiple: true` and the otherwise:

   ```
   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "event"=>{"title"=>"...", "event_category_ids"=>["", "1"]}, "commit"=>"Save"}
   ```

   `event_category_ids` in parameters sent is array, VS string in:

   ```
   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "event"=>{"title"=>"...", "event_category_ids"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
   ```

   It simply doesn't work because you only accept array in your event_params `event_category_ids: []`
2. Without any builder like [simple form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) you'll have to define selected value(s) manually.

   ```
   = f.collection_select(:event_category_ids, EventCategory.all, :id, :category, { selected: @event.event_category_ids }, {class: "form-select border border-dark", multiple: false})
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but at the moment I want to be able to select just one option in a dropdown menu, not a multiple select box.  Removing he array from the permitted params doesn't work though.

Comment: Are you sure? because i tested it myself while writing the answer and i confirmed it works. https://ibb.co/jV5yFjk

Comment: Apparently I had a typo in the params.  It's now working properly as I wanted it to.  Thanks!